# VBA: Range.Formula Returns Application Defined or Object Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

For my code, I am trying to find the difference between an objects value from two different days.

```
Sub GoingBack()

numberCube = InputBox("Which file are we going back to?")
numberYest = numberCube - 1

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\user\Downloads\file (" & numberCube & ").xlsx")
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\user\Downloads\file (" & numberYest & ").xlsx")

Set Work1 = Workbooks("file (" & numberCube & ").xlsx")
Set Work2 = Workbooks("file (" & numberCube - 1 & ").xlsx")

'Add the Time Difference Column (AA--27)
LastRow67 = Work1.Sheets("67").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Work1.Sheets("67").Cells(1, 27).Value = "Time Clock Difference"
Work1.Sheets("67").Cells(1, 27).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-15]-VLOOKUP(RC[-21], '[file (" & numberYest & ").xlsx]67'!$F:$L, 7, FALSE)"
Work1.Sheets("67").Range("AA2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA2:AA" & LastRow67)

Work1.Close savechanges:=True
Work2.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

The line that is throwing the "Application Defined or Object Defined" error is:

```
Work1.Sheets("67").Cells(1, 27).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-15]-VLOOKUP(RC[-21], '[file (" & numberYest & ").xlsx]67'!$F:$L, 7, FALSE)"
```

I have tried using Range.Formula, and that threw the error as well.

```
Work1.Sheets("67").Range("AA2").Formula = "=L2-VLOOKUP(F2, '[file (" & numberYest & ").xlsx]67'!$F:$L, 7, FALSE)"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

EDIT: I typed in the formula in Excel, and it works. I recorded the inputting of the formula, and the below is the result. I clicked/referenced columns F through L, so I'm not sure why it is only displaying C6:C12 below.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-15]-VLOOKUP(RC[-21],'[file.xlsx]67'!C6:C12,7,FALSE)"
```

Comment: First things first, manually type the formula in Excel and check if it works. If it does then update the question with that formula. Once we have that, it will be easy to adapt it in the code above

Comment: The first one wouldn't work as you mixed R1C1 and A1 style references. The second one looks OK though - is the sheet protected?

Comment: Always be explicit when using `Range`s. `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA2:AA" & LastRow67)` whose range is it here? See also [How to avoid using select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: @Rory the sheet is not protected.

Comment: @VincentG I have used this in many other macros that I have created, and I have not had an error yet, that is not what is throwing the error in this case.

Comment: Thats **C**olumn**6** to **C**olumn**12**

Comment: @JvDV I changed it to C6 to C12 and it worked! Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just because you've always done something a certain way, doesn't make it good practice. There are a lot of opportunities for improvement here.

Consider this refactor:

```
Option Explicit ' always!

Sub GoingBack()
    ' Dim all variables
    Dim numberCube As Variant
    Dim numberYest As Long
    Dim Work1 As Workbook
    Dim Work2 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow67 As Long
    Dim WorkSh1 As Worksheet
    Dim WorkSh2 As Worksheet
    Dim Pth As String

    ' avoid repeats of the same data
    Pth = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\"

    ' Might be better to use FileDialog, but anyway...
    ' Handle user cancel and invalid entry
    Do
        numberCube = InputBox("Which file are we going back to?")
        If numberCube = vbNullString Then
            ' User canceled, exit
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If IsNumeric(numberCube) Then Exit Do
        MsgBox "Enter a Number", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Loop
    numberYest = numberCube - 1

    ' Handle files missing or won't open
    On Error Resume Next
        Set Work1 = Workbooks.Open(Pth & "file (" & numberCube & ").xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Work1 Is Nothing Then
        'Work1 failed to open, what now?
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Work2 = Workbooks.Open(Pth & "file (" & numberYest & ").xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Work2 Is Nothing Then
        'Work2 failed to open, what now?
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    ' Set refences to worksheets and handle if missing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set WorkSh1 = Work1.Sheets("67")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WorkSh1 Is Nothing Then
        ' WorkSh1 doesn't exist, what now?
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set WorkSh2 = Work2.Sheets("67")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WorkSh2 Is Nothing Then
        ' WorkSh2 doesn't exist, what now?
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    'Add the Time Difference Column (AA--27)
    ' use your references
    With WorkSh1
        LastRow67 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(1, 27).value = "Time Clock Difference"
        ' no need for select or Autofill
        ' Can't use A1 style in FormulaR1C1
        .Range(.Cells(1, 27), .Cells(LastRow67, 27)).FormulaR1C1 = _
          "=RC[-15]-VLOOKUP(RC[-21], " & WorkSh2.Range("F:L").Address(, , xlR1C1, True) & ", 7, FALSE)"
    End With

CleanUp:
    Work1.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Work2.Close SaveChanges:=False ' you didn't change file 2

End Sub
```